# Locust. Read --host value from python code

Tags: python, locust

locust --no-web --client=1 --hatch-rate=1 --num-request=2 --host= http://localhost

I want to read --host value provided in cmd line in my HTTPLocust class. I am aware I can use host attribute for direct assignment but I do not want it. I want to read the value from cmd line with in HTTPLocust class. I am building custom logs and want to pass that value to the logs. I tried **HTTPLocust.host** but that returns none.

Also I want to read --web-port from python code.

Answer (score 5):

### New answer

There is a much more straightforward solution than my initial one below. Each `TaskSet` has a `locust` property that links back to their parent `Locust` [locustinstance](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#referencing-the-locust-instance-or-the-parent-taskset-instance), so something like this will do exactly what you need:

```py
class UserBehaviour(TaskSet):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        print(self.locust.host)
```

### Old answer

Looking at the [code for `HttpSession`](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/a13864f86a15fcd109420ceb7b1c866c0493e50c/locust/clients.py#L50-L53), it seems `base_url` is what you want.

So something like this should give you the current `host`, either default or specified on the command line:

```py
class HostGetter(locust.TaskSet):
    @locust.Task()
    def get_host(self):
        print(self.client.base_url)
```

Comment: Looks like the locust attribute has been removed from TaskSet in locust version 1.0 and later.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `host` variable by an instance of `User()`class. See the example below:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
import random, requests, time, os, inspect, json, sys


class UserBehaviour(TaskSet):
    @task(1)
    def test1(self):
        user = User()  
        print(user.host)
        self.client.get("/v3/User/ListOfCoupon/")

class User(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehaviour
    min_wait = 1000
    max_wait = 3000
```

see the log:

```
~/P/m/p/general (master ⚡↑) locust -f app_couponlist.py --host=http://www.google.com
[2017-09-19 14:33:13,020] Mesuts-MacBook.local/INFO/locust.main: Starting web monitor at *:8089
[2017-09-19 14:33:13,021] Mesuts-MacBook.local/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 0.8a3
[2017-09-19 14:33:22,281] Mesuts-MacBook.local/INFO/locust.runners: Hatching and swarming 5 clients at the rate 1 clients/s...
[2017-09-19 14:33:22,282] Mesuts-MacBook.local/INFO/stdout: http://www.google.com
[2017-09-19 14:33:22,282] Mesuts-MacBook.local/INFO/stdout:
[2017-09-19 14:33:23,285] Mesuts-MacBook.local/INFO/stdout: http://www.google.com
[2017-09-19 14:33:23,285] Mesuts-MacBook.local/INFO/stdout:
[2017-09-19 14:33:24,226] Mesuts-MacBook.local/INFO/stdout: http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my code:

```
import time,csv,argparse

class MySQLLocust(Locust):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--host', '--host')
    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
    print("Host = " + args.host)
```

Now when I give:

`locust -f mysql_locust.py --host=myhost-vm-101 --no-web --clients=2 --hatch-rate=10 --run-time=5m`

I get the print statement result as expected:

`Host = myhost-vm-101`

Answer (score 0):

You can access it via `sys.argv`

Or parse options via `argparse`

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-H', '--host')
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

print str(args.host)
```

Answer (score 0):

For locust v2.x this works for me:

```
class MyTaskSet(SequentialTaskSet):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        super().__init__(parent)

        user = parent
        while isinstance(parent, TaskSet):
            user = user.parent
        assert (isinstance(parent, User))

        self.host = user.environment.host
```